# How to set RGB Value for iOS Visualization segments?

Tags: ios, objective-c, colors, visualization, rgb

[image]

I am working on visualization tree map which shows the product categories.There are two values of any range.First value decides size of segments and second value decides the color of segments.Now the conditions is if value is +ve then color range must be vary between green color  and if -ve then value vary between red color (for big value color effect will be more dark and for small value color effect will be more light )
How do I done this .
the value ranges between 12 to 8 digits (- or +ve)

Help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want start by looking at the [`colorWithHue:saturation:brightness:alpha:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html) method of `UIColor`. The `hue` value will control choice between greens and reds. The `saturation` and/or `brightness` value will determine the "darkness", depending on what exactly you mean by "dark".

You can create a simple app with a UISliders for hue/sat/brightness and a UIView to display the selected color to experiment with HSB colors. Here's [a gist](https://gist.github.com/mmertsock/6045094) that implements such a tool.

Comment: I am confused for colorWithHue value.may be I have to find max and min value from my color values and calculate ratio and pass this ratio to colorwithHue.Is it?

Comment: cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:(float)index / (colorArray.count + 3)          saturation:1 brightness:0.75 alpha:1];

Comment: this is my code i wrote for color

Comment: "find max and min value...and calculate ratio" - that sounds like the general approach you would need to take, yes. Can't really comment on the code you posted though, would need to see more code and context to be able to understand it.